# Keras LSTM ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 923679, 63), found shape=(None, 63)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Anyone could help me on this ? I am still not sure why my input shape still remains the same

```
#Code 
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', 
    verbose=1,
    patience=10,
    mode='min',
    restore_best_weights=True)


n_steps = X_train.shape[0]
n_features = X_train.shape[1]
```

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

from tensorflow.keras import initializers

# create the LSTM model 
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.,
                                   input_shape=(n_steps, n_features))) 
model.add(LSTM(300, return_sequences=True, 
               dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))

model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01),metrics = METRICS)
print(model.summary())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nkFy.png)

```
batch_size = 1000
my_callbacks = [early_stopping]

neg = len(Y_train[Y_train ==0])
pos = len(Y_train[Y_train ==1])
total = neg + pos
weight_for_0 = (1 / neg)*(total)/2.0 
weight_for_1 = (1 / pos)*(total)/2.0

class_weight = {0: weight_for_0, 1: weight_for_1}

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 1000, batch_size=batch_size, 
                    validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), 
                    callbacks = my_callbacks, class_weight=class_weight,
                    verbose = 2, shuffle=True)
```

The problem is listed below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHMrI.png)

Comment: Do you actually have sequence data? If yes it should have shape (samples, timesteps, features).

Comment: My input shape is  (923679,63), not sure if it is what you mentioned of sequence data